# Vuejs use keep-alive to cache component properties

Tags: vuejs2, keep-alive

What I am trying to do is cache component properties with vue keep-alive.
But it seems not to cache the property values.

And here the benchmark-cards component where I use this number:

```
<div class="card-header">
    <h3 class="display-2 ctr">{{ avgClickRate }}<span class="percentage avg-ctr-percentage">%</span></h3>
</div>
```

I am using axios to get the data like this:

```
Axios.get(
        "/app_dev.php/general-benchmark/tags/" + this.$cookies.get("purposeId")
).then(
   function(response) {
     let tag = response.data.tag;
     this.tag = tag;

     let statistics = tag.statistics;
     let generalBenchmarkData = tag.generalBenchmark;

     this.clickThroughRatePercentage = Number(
         (generalBenchmarkData.activeCampaignClickThroughRate * 100).toFixed(0)
     );
)
```

Here is how I use it:

```
<keep-alive>
    <benchmark-cards :avgClickRate="clickThroughRatePercentage" :avgProjectWaste="avgProjectWaste"
                     :avgQualityScore="averageQualityScore"></benchmark-cards>
</keep-alive>
```

Answer (score 3):

In the [document](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#keep-alive)

> Note,  is designed for the case where it has one direct
> child component that is being toggled.

Some basic use-case:

```
<!-- basic -->
<keep-alive>
  <component :is="view"></component>
</keep-alive>

<!-- multiple conditional children -->
<keep-alive>
  <comp-a v-if="a > 1"></comp-a>
  <comp-b v-else></comp-b>
</keep-alive>

<!-- used together with `<transition>` -->
<transition>
  <keep-alive>
    <component :is="view"></component>
  </keep-alive>
</transition>
```

If your case, you didn't toggle between components, so it's useless to use `keep-alive`

For more example, in [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/1hzcok17/), every time you click on *Create Post*, `input-title` component is re-created again.

You might want to use [v-once](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-once) instead

Comment: Sounds logical, but when I bind the v-once the whole component isn't rendered at all. Because I bind a v-show="loaded" to it. So I want to render the component after loaded is true and render it once

Comment: If you use `v-if` instead of `v-show`, it might be ok. Or wrap in a parent component <parent v-if="loaded><child-component v-once/></parent>